# JSEncrypt is not defined coming when i am ruining ng test in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, ionic2, angular-cli

```
rsaencryption(data) {
    var encrypt = new JSEncrypt();
}
```

**i used like this in security.js file and i imported like below
'declare var JSEncrypt: any;' 
when i am running ng test  that time i am getting like**.

```
ReferenceError: JSEncrypt is not defined
at SecurityService.Array.concat.SecurityService.rsaencryption (http://localhost:9876/base/src/test.ts?5c53671ab11331130c37ebbdd5efa4f0d9bf5201:17318:23)
at SecurityService.Array.concat.SecurityService.doHmac (http://localhost:9876/base/src/test.ts?5c53671ab11331130c37ebbdd5efa4f0d9bf5201:17342:20)
at ApiPostman.Array.concat.ApiPostman.httpCall (http://localhost:9876/base/src/test.ts?5c53671ab11331130c37ebbdd5efa4f0d9bf5201:20310:48)
at otherBankAccountBenDetails.Array.concat.otherBankAccountBenDetails.countryListChanged (http://localhost:9876/base/src/test.ts?5c53671ab11331130c37ebbdd5efa4f0d9bf5201:62077:25)
at otherBankAccountBenDetails.Array.concat.otherBankAccountBenDetails.ngOnInit (http://localhost:9876/base/src/test.ts?5c53671ab11331130c37ebbdd5efa4f0d9bf5201:62046:14)
at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (http://localhost:9876/base/src/test.ts?5c53671ab11331130c37ebbdd5efa4f0d9bf5201:11196:19)
at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (http://localhost:9876/base/src/test.ts?5c53671ab11331130c37ebbdd5efa4f0d9bf5201:12619:17)
at checkAndUpdateNode (http://localhost:9876/base/src/test.ts?5c53671ab11331130c37ebbdd5efa4f0d9bf5201:12558:16)
at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (http://localhost:9876/base/src/test.ts?5c53671ab11331130c37ebbdd5efa4f0d9bf5201:13261:59)
at debugCheckDirectivesFn (http://localhost:9876/base/src/test.ts?5c53671ab11331130c37ebbdd5efa4f0d9bf5201:13202:13)**
```

Answer (score 0):

we should do like this

```
 var JSEncrypt = require('../../../assets/jsencrypt');
```

declare var JSEncrypt:any;